# Jumping token on a grid

Tags: mathematics, optimization

A token starts at location (0,0) on an infinite grid. On turn $n$ it must jump $n$ units horizontally or vertically, in one of four directions. What is the least number of turns needed for it to reach the location (10,10)? **Bonus:** what about location (100,100)? Good luck!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The token travels a distance of at least 20 to get to (10,10). Also, the total distance travelled

> must be even, because any distance travelled past 10 must be undone and hence travelled twice.
>  The first n for which the total distance 1+2+..+n is more than 20 and even is n=7, for a total of 28.
>  This has a surplus of 8=2*4, so we can just reverse the direction of the length 4 step to compensate. The steps can be made to reach (10,10) by for example (10,10) = (3+7, 1+2-4+5+6)

For (100,100) we can do the same thing.

> The first n for which 1+2+..+n is at least 200 and even is n=20.
>  Then 1+2+...+20 = 210, so flip the direction of the size 5 step to get rid of that surplus of 10. You can make 100 by 100=20+19+18+17+16+10 for example (there are many possibilities for this - I used the greedy method to find this one), and then the rest of the steps make up the other 100. This gives the solution:
>  (100,100) = (10+16+17+18+19+20, 1+2+3+4-5+6+7+8+9+11+12+13+14+15)

Comment: That is a brilliant answer! Very well explained.